# Docker drop changes on restart

Tags: docker

I'm using the following command to start docker container

```
# docker run --restart=always -d -p 80:80 image_name
```

And this means that docker daemon will restart the process if it exits, but it seems that the changes made in the container will remain after the process is restarted. Is there any way to make docker daemon drop all changes on process restart? I mean I want docker daemon to start a fresh container from image instead of restarting only the process.

Comment: Add the `-rm` flag to your command. This will remove the container once it stops.

Comment: @JonStirling Why don't you post this comment as an answer?

Comment: @jannis Good question ;)

Comment: Ive tried to do so and I've got "Conflicting options: --rm and -d", but detached mode is essential for me.

Comment: I've deleted the answer. Not only will it not work detached, but doing some more research it looks like it wouldn't work with the --restart option either.

Comment: The link posted by @nwinkler was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764197/how-can-i-run-containers-detached-and-have-them-automatically-removed-when-they which may still help.

Comment: Have your container clean itself up on init.   Or write your own restart script that removes it first.

Comment: Sure, I did it using a simple bash script, but I'm just curious about if there any out of the box solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way with the Docker Engine API.

The best idea is to run the container with --restart=no (default) parameter and use an external process monitor.  For example, if you have a RHEL-based OS you can use systemd unit files.  You would then control your container as a service.

I commonly do this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker create -d --name=container_name image_name
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start container_name
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop container_name
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/docker rm container_name  

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can also use docker-compose which has auto recreation options.